# Assigning letters to prime numbers using strings in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, encryption, prime-factoring

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm having a bit of trouble with my homework.
This is what I was given in the instructions:

> Encrypting:
>   “hi” => h->23, i->29 => h*i => 23*29 = 667
>   Decrypting:
>   667 => (prime factorization) 23*29 => 23->h 29->i => “hi”
>   Error Handling
>   What if someone enter a number that factorizes to other primes (out of list)?
>   Please choose the mode (Encrypt [e] / Decrypt [d]): d
>   Please enter an integer: 234234
>   null

And I have a code given:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Homework3 {

static int[] primes = {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103};
static String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please choose the mode (Encrypt [e] / Decrypt [d]): ");
    String mode = scan.next();
    String s = "";
    if (mode.equals("e")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a String: ");
        s = scan.next();
        System.out.println(">> " + encrypt(s));
    }
    else if (mode.equals("d")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
        s = scan.next();
        System.out.println(">> " + decrypt(s));
    }

}

// Examples:
// for s = "hi", return "667"
public static String encrypt(String s) {
    // Fill in the blanks
    return "";
}

// Examples:
// for x = "667", return "hi"
// for x = "327", return null
public static String decrypt(String x) {
    // Fill in the blanks
    return "";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any homework this quick in my life. Please check the edge cases.

```
public class Homework3 {

static int[] primes = {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103};
static String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
Map<Integer, Character> encryptMap = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
Map<Character, Integer> dencryptMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
   for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++){
     Character c = alphabet.charAt(i);
     encryptMap.put(primes[i], c);
     dencryptMap.put(c, primes[i]);
  } 

  //---your code


}
  public int encrypt(String s){
    if(s.length()==0) return 1;
    return encryptMap.get(s.charAt(0)) * encrypt(s.substring(1)); 
  }
  public String dencrypt(String s){
    Integer asInt = Integer.parseInt(s);
    List<Integer> factors = findFactors(asInt);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(Integer i: factors){
        builder.append(decryptMap.get(i));
    }
   String result = builder.toString();
   return result.length() == 0 ? null : result;
  }
   public List<Integer> findFactors(int number){
        int n = number;
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
      while (n % i == 0) {
        factors.add(i);
        n /= i;
      }
    }
    return factors;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nikola. There's a couple of compilation errors. You're accessing non-`static` variables from the `static` `main` method. You've also called the decryption map `dencryptMap` (sic) but referred to it later as `decrypt`. Also you `findFactors` method wastes time trying to find factors that aren't primes and won't be there. When `i==6` for example it will have already stripped out any factors of 2 and 3 in an earlier iteration of the loop. Harmless but you've got a list of primes provided on a plate.

Comment: thank you but i think this is too complicated for what we're doing. still, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution with a couple of caveats.

**Invalid Input**
It is not protected against a request to decrypt a non-number.
It will throw an exception - not normally an acceptable response to user error.

It still appears to have a bug because when I encrypt "cat" I get 7*3*73=1533 that's fine.

But when I decrypt 1533 I get "act" which is 3*7*73. Shome mishtake shurely! :)

I won't explain `encrypt()`. It's trivial.

`decrypt()` just works up through the primes seeing how many factors it can get of a each prime in order until the number reaches 1 (or zero though that's invalid input..).
That is divide by 3 as many times as you can. That's how many 'a's you have. 
Divide by 5 for the number of 'b's.
Etc.

Remember prime factorization is difficult only when you don't have a list of primes!

```
// Examples:
// for s = "hi", return "667"
public static String encrypt(String s) {
    int result=1;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i){
        int index=alphabet.indexOf(s.charAt(i));
        if(index!=-1){//Brutally ignore unknown characters.
            result=result*primes[index];
        }
    }
    return Integer.toString(result);
}

// Examples:
// for x = "667", return "hi"
// for x = "327", return null
public static String decrypt(String x) {
    if(x.equals("1")){
        return "";//Special case - the empty string.
    }
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(x.length()*2);
    int bix=Integer.parseInt(x);
    for(int i=0;i<primes.length;++i){
        int p=primes[i];
        for(;;){
            if(bix%p==0){
                builder.append(alphabet.charAt(i));
                bix=bix/p;
                if(bix==1){
                    break;
                }   
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        if(bix<=1){
            break;
        }       
    }
    if(bix!=1){
        //something went wrong.
        builder.append("?");//Do what you like with errors...
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: first of all, thank you very much! the problem you mentioned is not a problem at all, i'm allowed to have that bug. however, we have a test code that grades us, and i have a problem. the code you wrote prints out short words and integers perfectly, however when you write a longer word, for example computer, it outputs a negative value, and when you put in a long integer it won't run at all. so should i use the biginteger or something? again, thanks a lot!

Comment: I thought that might be acceptable behaviour. An obvious way to make it a real encoding is to follow the model provided by Kurt Gödel and use primes to the power of codes and use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. For longer messages that method will overflow. I actually did it with `BigInteger` to begin with but decided that might be beyond the scope of your work. I'd hate you to hand in homework you didn't understand. I leave modifying it to `BigInteger` as your real homework. Or you could just repost it on Stackoverflow...